# EXTJS how to get the component without declare id?

Tags: extjs

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   alias: 'widget.mygrid',
   header: false,
   store: UserStore,
   multiSelect: false,
   columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: '_id',

                    text: 'Vehicle ID'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 126,
                    dataIndex: 'Plat_No',
                    text: 'Plat Number'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 200,
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    text: 'Added By'
                }
            ]
})
```

i dont have any id declare in the gridpanel, because it will used in dynamicly,
so, i m using alias to find my grid component like below code

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mygrid');
        console.log( Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mygrid') );
        if (grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) { //error at here 
           var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
           console.log(row.get('Plat_No'));
        };
```

But, firebug return error with `TypeError: grid.getSelectionModel is not a function`

any other way to find my gridpanel component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query) returns an **array** of matched Components from within the passed root object.

So if you have only one `mygrid` component in your application, you can get your grid like this:

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mygrid')[0];
```

Comment: have any better solution? maybe use classname `MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel` is better accuracy?

Comment: Using `classname` have same accurancy as using alias. Your solution is not wrong. You just have to count with that this query will return array of all instances of `mygrid` which exists in your application. More accurate will be using `query()` with second parameter or `up()` or `down()` methods from some parent or child component.

Comment: Thanks for your helping hand, u r always helping me